# Is avg 160ms a slow round-trip? If yes, how do I improve it?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

My mac is connected to the Wi-Fi hotspot device through cable while my phone is through wireless of course.

Here is the stats generated by the terminal on my mac to ping my phone.

```
--- 192.168.1.190 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 33.682/160.694/404.684/129.886 ms
```

Here is the stats to the gateway, the WIFI itself, from my mac.

```
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.489/0.545/0.617/0.053 ms
```

Here is the stats to the gateway, from my phone.

```
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 8.579/16.015/26.660/6.242 ms
```

Is it a little bit slow? How do I trouble shoot my network?

Comment: Is the 160 ms a consistent average? Maybe there was some electrical interference just when you tried it that time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very slow.
There are a few ways to improve it like closing other apps using your internet,  check if there are any background apps running that are using your internet or if there is any update running, or update your network drivers. If you’re still getting a high ping, try and move your device nearer your router or, better still, connect your computer or console directly to your router using an Ethernet cable. If none of those work, then try changing your ISP.